# How to do GROUP BY on Sub Selected Column in SQL

Tags: sql

Say for example I am doing this query:

```
SELECT 
   W.UserID, 
   W.Number,
   (SELECT StatusDate FROM WStatuses AS WS WHERE WS.Number = W.NUmber AND WS.StatusType = 'CRFI') AS StatusDate
   W.Model
FROM WorkOrder AS W

GROUP BY MONTH(StatusDate)
```

How can i d this behavior? There is a WORKORDER table and a WORKORDERSTATUS table. The WORKORDER table has one entry per work order number. The WORKORDERSTATUS table has a history of all WORKORDERSTATUS changes for that one work order number.  So i am pulling only the date for when it had the status changed to CRFI. I then need to group by the months in that column returned, and says it is not a valid column. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and happy coding!

Comment: What kind of aggregation do you want per month? Just a count of the records, or a sum of some column?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your non-working query may not adequately convey what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub-query approach

```
SELECT MONTH(StatusDate), sum(w.Number) num
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     W.UserID, 
     W.Number,
     (SELECT StatusDate FROM WStatuses AS WS WHERE WS.Number = W.NUmber AND WS.StatusType = 'CRFI') AS StatusDate
     W.Model
  FROM WorkOrder AS W
) T
GROUP BY MONTH(StatusDate)
```

alternative approach (IF you are sure that only one record will return from WStatuses with filter `CRFI`)

```
SELECT 
   avg(W.Number),
   MONTH(StatusDate)
FROM WorkOrder AS W
INNER JOIN Wstatuses 
  on WS.Number = W.NUmber AND WS.StatusType = 'CRFI'
GROUP BY MONTH(StatusDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider avoiding the correlated subquery (that calculates for *every* row) for a more efficient `JOIN`. Additionally, include all non-aggregated columns listed in `SELECT` clause into the `GROUP BY` clause which is the **correct** way to run aggregate queries to the ANSI standard. And run needed aggregations as shown in below adjustment.

```
SELECT 
   W.UserID, 
   W.Number,
   MONTH(S.StatusDate) AS StatusMonth
   W.Model,
   COUNT(...) AS CountAgg,
   SUM(...) AS SumAgg,
   AVG(...) AS AvgAgg,
   ...
FROM WorkOrder AS W
INNER JOIN WStatuses AS S
  ON S.Number = W.NUmber AND S.StatusType = 'CRFI'

GROUP BY W.UserID, 
         W.Number,      
         MONTH(S.StatusDate)
         W.Model
```

Comment: Great answer too and thank you very much. Sorry for delayed update i ended up working it out.